# Tycho - unpacked plugin option is ignored

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I have setup a `tycho` build with `maven`, which builds the features and plugins like a charm.

The issue is that even if I explicitly set `unpack="true"` in my plugin entry of `feature.xml`, the feature isn't unpacked in the `target` folder, while it should.

Tycho version: `1.0.0`

My plugin entries from the `feature.xml` file:

```
<plugin
     id="xx.xx.xx"
     download-size="0"
     install-size="0"
     version="2.0.3.qualifier"
     unpack="false"/>
<plugin
     id="should.be.unpacked"
     download-size="0"
     install-size="0"
     version="1.1.2.qualifier"
     unpack="true"/>
<plugin
     id="xx.xx.xx"
     download-size="0"
     install-size="0"
     version="1.0.0.qualifier"
     unpack="false"/>
<plugin
     id="xx.xx.xx"
     download-size="0"
     install-size="0"
     version="1.1.1.qualifier"
     unpack="false"/>
<plugin
     id="xx.xx.xx"
     download-size="0"
     install-size="0"
     version="1.0.0.qualifier"
     unpack="false"/>
```

I don't have a specific `pom.xml` file for the feature as I enable pomless builds for tycho.

Answer (score 1):

See this Eclipse Bugzilla:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409097
So basically Tycho doesn't care about the feature attribute 'unpack', if you want to have a plugin or fragment unpacked, you have to specify the following in MANIFEST.MF of the plugin/fragment:

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think `unpack="true"` can do what you are after: It controls whether when feature will be unpacked when installed into a product, not whether it will be stored **temporarily** in unpacked form below your project’s `target` directory. (In particular, even if `unpack="true"` is set, Tycho will always pack your feature to install it as a single file in your local Maven repository.)

Why do you need the feature to be unpacked in your `target` folder anyway? Is it consumed there by a later step in your build? If so, a [simple `dependency:unpack` execution](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) may be more what you.

Comment: That's for a lter step yes, how would one add dependency:unpack on one plugin only? I'm kind of a newbie with tycho and maven in general.

Comment: What do you mean by “on one plugin only”? Do you want to process the unpacked feature as part of the `eclipse-feature` project’s build itself? Or do you want to do at in a later project in the same reactor (AKA, the same `mvn clean install` invocation)? Finally, what are you trying to do? Maybe there’s a more direct way to do it with Tycho.